# How to list all subdirectory using nodeJS SFTP client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, sftp, ftp-client

Amusing node JS ssh2-sftp-client. I want to the list all the directory and its subdirectories in a given path?

```
 let sftp = new ssh2SftpClient();
console.log(sftp);
sftp.connect({
    host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    port: '22',
    username: 'centos',
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('/home/myHome/aws_int.ppk')
}).then(() => {
    return sftp.list('/home/centos/myHome');
}).then((data) => {
    console.log('the data info : ' + data);
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[i].name);
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('catch error : ' + err);
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('catch error : ' + err);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client

The above code returns only the directories in the given path but not its subdirectories.

Answer (score -3):

why are you using username/ password? sftp is supposed to use ssh keys. once the keys are shared, you dont need password.. you should be able to connect with the username.

Comment: host : hostname,
    port : port,
    username : username,
    //privateKey :  fs.readFileSync('/home/myHome/server/int/aws__int.ppk'),
    password : password

Comment: yes connecting with ppk file.  that is just a template @Narayana

Comment: does the username have proper permissions across to access all folders and sub-folders on the remote location?

Comment: yes. having. no permission issue. because if I pass folder by folder, I can able to get a list of directories.

Comment: @Narayana, why is this posted as answer? it sounds more like a comment to me. It doesn't address any problem asked by OP.